# How do I find the lowest and highest value of an array as well as the array squared and the array reversed?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a code that will give me the highest and lowest number in an array as well as the array squared and the reversed array. I keep getting 0's when I run the program but no other problem, so something is set equal to wrong but I can't figure out what's wrong because there's no error messages. Here's the code:

```
using System;

namespace ArrayMethods
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an array size: ");
            int someArray = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            int[] Array = new int[someArray];

            String input = Console.ReadLine();

            int[] arrayPart3 = new int[10];

            ReversedArray(arrayPart3);
            for (int index = 0; index < arrayPart3.Length; index++)
            {
                Console.Write(arrayPart3[index] + "| ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Largest is:" + ArrayMax(arrayPart3));
            Console.WriteLine("Smallest is:" + ArrayMin(arrayPart3));

            SquaredArray(arrayPart3);
            for (int index = 0; index<arrayPart3.Length; index++)
            {
                Console.Write(arrayPart3[index] + "| ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            ReversedArray(arrayPart3);
            for (int index = 0; index < arrayPart3.Length; index++)
            {
                Console.Write(arrayPart3[index] + "| ");
            }

        }

        public static int ArrayMax(int[] someArray)
        {
            int highest = someArray[0];
            for (int index = 0; index < someArray.Length; index++)
            {
                if (someArray[index] > highest)
                    highest = someArray[index];
            }
            return highest;
        }

        public static int ArrayMin(int[] someArray)
        {
            int lowest = someArray[0];
            for (int index = 0; index < someArray.Length; index++)
            {
                if (someArray[index] < lowest)
                    lowest = someArray[index];
            }
            return lowest;
        }

        public static void SquaredArray(int[]someArray)
        {

            for (int index = 0; index < someArray.Length; index++)
            {
                 someArray[index] = someArray[index] * someArray[index];
            }

        }


        public static void ReversedArray(int[] someArray)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index<someArray.Length; index++)
            {
                int temp = someArray[index];
                someArray[index] = someArray[someArray.Length - 1 - index];
                someArray[someArray.Length - 1 -index] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ's `Min`, `Max` and `Reverse` would be worth a look. I am not sure what you mean by `array squared`.

Comment: @mjwills What I mean by array squared is each number in the array is squared

Comment: I may be a bit blind, but It doesn't seem like you are setting any values to the array/arrays you want to reverse and do all those things. Print the array before you do any operation on them to check they have what you expect. It seems to me like you are reading from the console the arraySize and nothing else (but I may be just totally missign where you get the array values XD). Also I would advice against calling an array "Array".

Comment: @Techgeekgal19 `var bob = originalArray.Select(z => (long)z * z).ToArray();`

Comment: if this is homework and you have limitations on what you are allowed to use, then you should specify that in the question, otherwise people will propose using standard library functions to do all this.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score -1):

the code of parsing the input is missing

here is a compact linq based code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        // or use a fixed input: var input = "1 2 3 4";
        int[] arrayPart3 = input.Split(' ',',', ';').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Reversed: " + string.Join("| ", arrayPart3.Reverse()));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Largest is:" + arrayPart3.Max());
        Console.WriteLine("Smallest is:" + arrayPart3.Min());
        Console.WriteLine("Squared: " + string.Join("| ", arrayPart3.Select(i => i*i)));
        Console.WriteLine("Reversed Squared: " + string.Join("| ", arrayPart3.Reverse().Select(i => i*i)));

    }
}
```

Comment: upvoted,  but I'd seperate out the two parts, her main problem is the lack of parsing the input.   The Linq is just an alternative, and technically doesn't actually do the same thing, as hers mutates the array.

Comment: my guess is the actual input parsing is supposed to be Enter the size, followed by a for loop that loops through that size asking for each value of the array as a readline.....

Comment: @KeithNicholas is this kind of question valid in SO though? Because if this person had debugged or printed the input they would have known. I am asking because I am unsure about this.

Comment: @Dzyann It's in a semi fuzzy area, it's a new user who has asked a question where the title is really the wrong question, their problem is something quite different, so the question should be edited.  The question then becomes dodgy because essentially they forgot to do something.  So then, yes, it should be closed.  However, there seems to be a certain tolerance for questions where the author is having trouble identifying their real problems and often end up with good answers.  It's the dilema of SO, should we be real pedants for the rules? or alow some tolerance? rehashed many times on meta

Comment: @KeithNicholas yeah, I never know what to do. However we can help him and still close the question. Because I can't see how this question could add value. He totally forgot to get input value. If he had done that MVE thing probably would have noticed, I don't think we should be mean though. Anyways thanks for clarifying, it is sucha  grey area.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @user287107 System.Linq provides most of these functions out of the box, for the squaring you can use a simple Select extension method Func.

Here is an ArrayUtils class I quickly wrote to provide the functionality you are looking for:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class ArrayUtils
    {
        public int GetMax(int[] arr)
        {
            return arr.Max();
        }

        public int GetMin(int[] arr)
        {
            return arr.Min();
        }

        public int[] GetReverse(int[] arr)
        {
            return arr.Reverse().ToArray();
        }

        public int[] SquareValues(int[] arr)
        {
            return arr.Select(x => x * x).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not her problem

Comment: @Techgeekgal19 The usage context is not clear, for one thing `String input = Console.ReadLine();` is read from the console but is never used, what is supposed to be being manipulated?

This is likely the reason everything is 0, you just created an empty array of `int[10]`, the user input is completely ignored other than the original request for the array size.